# Java Hibernate List - Called inside a thread is slow

Tags: java, hibernate

I am currently making a hibernate call as such

```
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("TIME: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-currTimeLong));
            List results = query.list(); //VERY SLOW IN THREADS
            System.out.println("TIME: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-currTimeLong));
```

Now, I am making multiple such calls for a server application. Hence, I decided to simultaneously run them by wrapping this operation in Runnables/Threads.

When I did that, query.list() became insanely slow. Almost by 1000+ milliseconds. Why does hibernate's query.list() run so much slower when wrapped in a thread? Does it make a call to the main thread somehow?

Comment: Are you creating a separate session per thread, or are multiple threads using the same session?

Comment: I am getting the current session from HibernateUtils.currentSession

Comment: Every call SQL call that I make right now has Session session = HibernateUtils.currentSession(); This particular call of getting a session is fast. It's the query.list() that is slow. I've narrowed it down to that

Comment: What is `HibernateUtils`? Please add the code to the original post

Comment: If you run a single query using the wrapped code, is it slow? Or only when you have multiple simultaneous queries? If the latter, it may be a database issue and nothing to do with your java code.

Comment: Even when I have just one hibernate query running in a thread, it is still slower than if running in the main thread